# How do I change what input.value returns?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Can I change the value of `input.value`?

For example:

```
<input type="text" value="a" id="i" />

var input = document.getElementById("i");
input.value; // I want this to return double of input.value, that is "aa" in this case.
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a string concatenation:

```
var input = document.getElementById("i");
var result = input.value + input.value;
```

Comment: No, that's not what I like...I just want to use `var result = input.value;` and `result` is "aa"

Comment: @wong2, no, I am afraid that's not possible.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I found a method: `input.__defineGetter__("value", function(){return "t";})` but it seems not support IE

Comment: @wong2, no, IE does not support this. I am afraid that currently you cannot achieve this in a cross browser way.

Answer (score 2):

Best you can achieve is "extend" the generic HTML Input element by adding your own method:

```
HTMLInputElement.prototype.MyValue = function() {
    return this.value + this.value;
};
```

Then call it instead of the `.value` property:

```
var input = document.getElementById("i");
alert(input.MyValue());
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/ETQyJ/) - working on the recent version of all major browsers. (Chrome, Firefox, IE)